# Approximating relative angle between two line segments on sphere surface

Tags: matlab, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I am in need of an idea! I want to model the vascular network on the eye in 3D. I have made statistics on the branching behaviour in relation to vessel diameter, length etc. What I am stuck at right now is the visualization:

The eye is approximated as a sphere `E` with center in origo `C = [0, 0, 0]` and a radius `r`.

**What I want to achieve** is that based on the following input parameters, it should be able to draw a segment on the surface/perimeter of `E`:

*Input:*

- Cartesian position of previous segment ending: `P_0 = [x_0, y_0, z_0]`
- Segment length: `L`
- Segment diameter: `d`
- Desired angle relative to the previous segment: `a` (1)

*Output:*

- Cartesian position of resulting segment ending: `P_1 = [x_1, y_1, z_1]`

**What I do now**, is the following:

1. From `P_0`, generate a sphere with radius `L`, representing all the points we could possibly draw to with the correct length. This set is called `pool`.
2. Limit `pool` to only include points with a distance to `C` between `r*0.95` and `r`, so only the points around the perimeter of the eye are included.
3. Select only the point that would generate a relative angle (2) closest to the desired angle `a`.

**The problem is**, that whatever angle `a` I desire, is actually not what is measured by the dot product. Say I want an angle at 0 (i.e. that the new segment is following the same direction as the previous`, what I actually get is an angle around 30 degrees because of the curvature of the sphere. I guess what I want is more the 2D angle when looking from an angle orthogonal from the sphere to the branching point. Please take a look at the screenshots below for a visualization.

Any ideas?

---

(1) The reason for this is, that the child node with the greatest diameter is usually follows the path of the previous segment, whereas smaller child nodes tend to angle differently.

(2) Calculated by `acos(dot(v1/norm(v1), v2/norm(v2)))`

---

Screenshots explaining the problem:

Yellow line: previous segment
Red line: "new" segment to one of the points (not neccesarily the correct one)
Blue x'es: Pool (text=angle in radians)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you want to do: Sphere-cylinder intersection? (With cylinder-axis passing through origin?). i.e. You want to draw circles on the sphere?

Comment: It is not really clear what the *segment* is you are talking about. Is it a circular segment on the sphere? Is the diameter of this segment meant as being measured *on the sphere* or *cutting through the sphere*? In either of those cases creating a sphere at point `P_0` won't be sufficient. If you mean radius of the circular segment measured *cutting through* the sphere, you need a cylinder, if you mean measured *on the sphere* you need something different.

Comment: "Segment" is basically the line segments. From one branching point to another. Also, diameter is merely for visualization and is not relevant in the discussion of which direction to draw.

Comment: If *segment* is a (straight) line, how come it has a length and diameter?

Comment: Never mind the diameter. In my final program, segment is a rectangle and not a line. Update: cylinder

Comment: I'm still confused. What is your actual input based on which you want to draw something and how should this input be translated to those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will restate the problem with my own notation:

> Given two points P and Q on the surface of a sphere centered at C with radius r, find a new point T such that the angle of the turn from PQ to QT is A and the length of QT is L.

Because the segments are small in relation to the sphere, we will use a locally-planar approximation of the sphere at the pivot point Q. (If this isn't an okay assumption, you need to be more explicit in your question.)

You can then compute T as follows.

```
// First compute an aligned orthonormal basis {U,V,W}.
//  - {U,V} should be a basis for the plane tangent at Q.
//  - W should be normal to the plane tangent at Q.
//  - U should be in the direction PQ in the plane tangent at Q
W = normalize(Q - C)
U = normalize(Q - P)
U = normalize(U - W * dotprod(W, U))
V = normalize(crossprod(W, U))

// Next compute the next point S in the plane tangent at Q.
// In a regular plane, the parametric equation of a unit circle
// centered at the origin is:
//     f(A) = (cos A, sin A) = (1,0) cos A + (0,1) sin A
// We just do the same thing, but with the {U,V} basis instead
// of the standard basis {(1,0),(0,1)}.
S = Q + L * (U cos A + V sin A)

// Finally project S onto the sphere, obtaining the segment QT.
T = C + r * normalize(S - C)
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. That indeed looks like what I am looking for. I will try to implement it when I get the chance later today.

Comment: That does not quite do it. A further requirement is that T should also be located on the sphere. 

This gives a constraint on the angle, but the angle we are looking for is in fact the angle when looking orthogonally towards the branching point. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @c.jespersen Sorry I accidentally left out a step. See the edit.  S is the next point in the tangent plane at Q.  T is then S projected onto the sphere.

Comment: That works. Amazing. Can I ask you to put a couple of words to each vector, its role, etc.?

Comment: @c.jespersen I added some explanation and also added an additional (maybe unnecessary) step to project U onto the plane tangent at Q.